# in Internet Explorer 8, view source with Notepad

Tags: internet-explorer-8

How can I set Internet Explorer 8 the old style "view source" to open with Notepad?

(I set HTML editing to Notepad, but I want the Right-Click - View source to open in notepad)

Comment: What features are missing from the view you get now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the registry. Open **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source Editor\Editor Name**, then enter the program including the completly qualified path that you want to use.

*ie: C:\Windows\notepad.exe*

Comment: (Default) = C:\Windows\notepad.exe

Comment: In IE11/Win7 the key is under HKEY_CURRENT_USER, not HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Answer (score 1):

This page here should help

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/default-view-source-editor-changed-in-ie8/